# Snowflake Error: SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 6 invalid identifier 'INTERNAL_ID'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running into an issue when I try to query a view. I can successfully pull the data without a WHERE clause, but when I add a WHERE clause it fails.

Good Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM V_WMS_STG_BI_DMLABOR
```

Failed Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM V_WMS_STG_BI_DMLABOR
WHERE Internal_ID = 5587640
```

I tried to add single and/or double quotes to the Internal_ID and value without any success. I added single quotes to the Internal_ID ('Internal_ID') but the query didn't return any data. I also added single quotes to both the identifier and value, it removed error but no data was returned.

Here is sample data that should be returned.
[Sample Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjiLI.png)

Here is the schema for the view [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0n8q.png)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you schema shows the column as Internal_ID which implies you need to use double quotes to tell snowflake to not auto uppercase the column name, thus "Internal_ID". The trick is you have to have the case 100% correct when you put it inside double quotes.

You can double click the column name in the UI editor to have it past it into the SQL editor with the correct quotes/casing.

The value should not need quotes as it's a number, and single quotes is for strings.

thus:

```
SELECT *
FROM V_WMS_STG_BI_DMLABOR
WHERE "Internal_ID" = 5587640
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you Simeon! I appreciate your help.